# Unity Google Play Game Services callback returning false when App was not installed

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

In the first place I don't understand why user should first install Google Play Games App if my Unity Android App is using Google Play Game Services API, Is there any SDK equivalent to the Facebook SDK that I can use for Google login.
Worse case even if Google Play Games app needs to be installed, then callback should wait for a response. Even after installing the app, and successfully signing, it is giving false. As a result, my login process has now become 2 step process. First time user installs the Google Play Games app and second time he is able to login.
Is there a better way to implement Google authentication.

Piece of code that I have used to implement auth system is:

```
public void Start()
    {
        //Initialize Google Play
        Debug.Log("Activating google play games");
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new 
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()

            .Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled=false;
        GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();


    }

//Called from a UI Button
public void GooglePlusStart() 
   {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            //Do something depending on the success achieved
            if (success) {
                Debug.Log("Login success");
                getdetails = true;
            }  else {
                var props = new Value();
                props["entered_code"] = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("CurrentCode");
                props["reason"] = "Google Signup Error";
                Mixpanel.Track ("Google Signup",props);
                SignupUtils.ShowError("google");
                Debug.Log("Login failure");
            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: Try [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) with your Unity game as it supports Google Login, Facebook Login, Twitter Login and more. Check the Firebase guide for [Google Sign-in with Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/google-signin).

Comment: I remember trying Firebase SDK first, but its example was only not running and sdk was itself not working. This was the reason why I used Play Game Services.